# What is the best way to get a proper type name from a C# keyword?

Tags: c#

I want to create a type using Type.GetType( nameOfTheType ), where nameOfTheType is some string. If nameOfTheType is "System.String", this works great. If nameOfTheType is "string", this throws an exception. All types with keyword shortcuts fail.

Is there a way, other than a big switch statement, to correctly map all of the types with keyword shortcuts to their actual type names (as per this list: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya5y69ds%28VS.80%29.aspx)?

Edit: Gabriel has correctly pointed out that the MSDN page I linked does not include nullable types (int?, etc.), but it is important that nullable types are mapped correctly as well.

Comment: Do you want it to work for the nullables too?  Eg. int? , double? etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Disclaimer**
Let me start out by saying that the method I'm going to demonstrate here is purely for educational purposes. Please use the switch or dictionary lookups demonstrated in the other answers in your production code.

**Answer**
So, the only way to find out how the compiler would interpret a given piece of code is to actually compile it and inspect the generated assembly. This isn't so hard to do in .NET... You could compile an arbitrary string during runtime using the C# compiler like so:

```
private static Type GetTypeByFullNameOrAlias(string typeName)
{
  Type type = Type.GetType(typeName);

  if (type == null)
  {
    using (var provider = new CSharpCodeProvider())
    {
      var compiler = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(
        new CompilerParameters
          {GenerateInMemory = true, GenerateExecutable = false, IncludeDebugInformation = false},
        "public class A { public " + typeName + " B; }");

      type = ((FieldInfo)compiler.CompiledAssembly.GetType("A").GetMember("B")[0]).FieldType;
    }
  }

  return type;
}
```

However, this technique has several drawbacks... First of all it is slow. Of course you could cache the result and do other trickery to speed up the process. But there's another problem, which is that it compiles and loads a complete assembly each time it reaches the inside of the "if" statement. Each assembly it loads cannot be unloaded again and will hang around until the application closes, so this technique will also leak a small amount of memory. Again, you could load the generated assembly into an separate AppDomain and unload the domain after you've inspected the type but that would only make the code a lot slower.

But as I pleaded in the beginning, just use the "switch" solution in your production code... It does a perfectly good job of translating the aliases. And it's not like they're going to change those language aliases anytime soon.

Comment: I don't know why people are so concerned on my behalf about performance when they don't know the context, but this is the best answer. Nullable types nearly doubled the number of type aliases, and this code would have survived that while a switch statement would not have.  Thanks.

Comment: For those interested, in order to get a proper round trip of typeAsString -> typeObject -> typeAsString, you need to do this:

provider.GetTypeOutput( new CodeTypeReference( type ) )

Otherwise, nullable types such as int? try to turn into "System.Nullable`1".

Comment: I really hope something like this never reaches production code.

Comment: @ChaosPandion: I agree... Personally I would use the switch or your dictionary solution instead. However, the technique I show can be very useful in rare cases. And this solution is also the only one that actually answers the question "is there a way **other** than a switch". ;)

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [CodeDom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.aspx) to create a [CodeVariableDeclarationStatement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.codevariabledeclarationstatement.aspx), and retrieve the Type property:

```
var stmt = new CodeVariableDeclarationStatement("string", "test");
string systemTypeName = stmt.Type.BaseType;
```

I am not sure whether you can use CodeDom classes that independently, but it should be an easy way to get from "string" to "System.String" without needing to create a lookup function using *switch*.

EDIT:

Thinking about it more, it *may* be possible to simply use a [CodeTypeReference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.codetypereference.aspx) directly, and shortcut the process above:

```
var systemTypeName = new CodeTypeReference("string").BaseType;
```

The CodeVariableDeclarationStatement.Type property is a CodeTypeReference. By using CodeTypeReference directly, you don't need to bother with a dummy variable name, and it can become a one-liner.

WORKING EXAMPLE:

I found the code that did this previously. It is a bit more complicated than I had hoped, but it gets the job done, and if the generated classes are cached, performance is good after initial compilation:

```
using System;
using System.CodeDom;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;

using Microsoft.CSharp;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public interface IDynamicTypeNameMapper
    {
        string GetTypeName();
    }

    class Program
    {
        static readonly string[] csharpKeywords = new[]
        {
            "byte",
            "short",
            "int",
            "long",
            "float",
            "double",
            "string"
        };

        static Dictionary<string, IDynamicTypeNameMapper> s_mappers;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            s_mappers = new Dictionary<string, IDynamicTypeNameMapper>();

            var provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
            var options = new CompilerParameters();
            options.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("ConsoleApplication1.exe");
            options.GenerateInMemory = true;

            var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopwatch.Start();
            foreach (string keyword in csharpKeywords)
            {
                string className = "DynamicTypeNameMapper_" + keyword;
                string literal = "using System; using ConsoleApplication1; namespace Test { public class " + className + ": IDynamicTypeNameMapper { public string GetTypeName() { return typeof(" + keyword + ").FullName; } } }";
                var snippet = new CodeSnippetCompileUnit(literal);

                var results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromDom(options, snippet);

                var typeNameMapper = results.CompiledAssembly.CreateInstance("Test." + className) as IDynamicTypeNameMapper;
                if (typeNameMapper != null)
                {
                    s_mappers.Add(keyword, typeNameMapper);
                    Console.WriteLine(typeNameMapper.GetTypeName());
                }
            }
            stopwatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Inital time: " + stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString());

            stopwatch.Reset();
            stopwatch.Start();

            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                foreach (string keyword in csharpKeywords)
                {
                    s_mappers[keyword].GetTypeName();
                }
            }
            stopwatch.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine("Cached time: " + stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString());

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

The output of this app is as follows:

```
System.Byte
System.Int16
System.Int32
System.Int64
System.Single
System.Double
System.String
Inital time: 00:00:00.3090559
Cached time: 00:00:00.0011934
```

Comment: Very short and slick. The user doesn't have to maintain a switch statement of types and it will still automatically work if Microsoft were to expand the data types of C# for any reason.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work: in both cases, systemTypeName evaluates to just "string" on .NET 3.5.  That said, there should be a way to make this work with CodeDom, but you'll probably need to use the CSharpCodeProvider, since the run-time only speaks IL.

Comment: This is more along the lines of what I'm looking for. But, as Gabriel says, it doesn't appear to work. It's too bad there isn't a way to tell the framework to evaluate an alias, as the keywords are just aliases to fully qualified types.

Comment: I have used the CodeDom to get the .NET System name of types before. The BaseType property may be the incorrect property. Try using CodeTypeReferenceOptions.GlobalReference...I think that will force it to map the System type for you.

Comment: I tried CodeTypeReferenceOptions.GlobalReference before I commented and it didn't seem to improve the situation. I could be missing something, still.

Comment: Well, I am having some problems with one of my hard drives at the moment. As soon as I have a chance, I'll try to figure out how I did it before. It should be possible, but it may not be quite as simple as I was thinking. :\

Comment: To get this working you would have to run the CodeDom output through the compiler, which would be extremely inefficient.  The switch statement or table is better.

Comment: I have added a working example, including timings. Initial compilation requires 0.3 seconds for all seven of the example C# keywords, and 0.001 seconds for 1000 retrievals of the full type names using cached instances of the generated classes. Once cached, execution is orders of magnitude faster than the minimal initial hit, executing as if you had written the code and compiled it ahead of time.

Comment: @Ray Burns: Yes it would be slow the first time a keyword is compiled, but it is more "future proof" this way.  And there's nothing stopping you from caching the results: successes can be cached permanently, since keywords will (likely) never be removed; and failures can be cached within a single launch--so that new keywords can be added between launches.   But maybe this is all overkill...

Comment: @Ray Burns: I have to dispute the "extremely" inefficient remark. Take a look at the working example I provided, and see the timings for yourself. The initial compilation, while there is a hit, is still only a fraction of a second for all seven of the test keywords. Even assuming there were a couple dozen value type keywords, were talking a single second to compile them ONCE, after which each type name evaluator executes in normal, compiled time. A simple utility class could be written to support mapping type names from any .NET language with ease, providing a dynamic, future-proof solution.

Comment: @jrista: First off, your revised example is great--very cool.  Also, if you append .Replace("?","nullable") to `keyword` in the definition of `classname` in your revised answer, you get automatic support for nullables (`int?`, `double?`) as well, which is cool (though maybe beyond what OP asked for).  in fact, there might be a straightforward way to mangle arbitrary layers (e.g. `List<int?>?` , etc, and even future, not-yet-defined forms) into "class_name"-able strings, just a thought.

Comment: @Gabriel: To support any type name, you would simply need to make sure that the generated class name did not contain any invalid characters. Once you did that, it should be possible to use this to get the type name of any type for any .NET language (as long as it has CodeDom support and a .NET compiler provider). It would work for future, not-yet-defined type keywords and the like as well.

Answer (score 2):

System.String *is* the type name, 'string' is an alias.  The following code works for me, so perhaps I don't get your use case:

```
string s = "";
Type t = Type.GetType( s.GetType( ).ToString( ) );
Console.WriteLine( t );  // prints "System.String"
```

... which of course is completely redundant as you could just ask 's' for its type :)

EDIT:
After seeing the comment below, you may just need to make a switch.  The problem is that Type.GetType() wants a fully qualified name, and (after some searching) I could not find a way to match an alias to its type name.  If someone does find that, awesome, but something like this would work well enough:

```
switch (userType)
{
    case "string": return "System.String";
    case "sbyte": return "System.SByte";
    case "byte": return "System.Byte";
    case "short": return "System.Int16";
    case "ushort": return "System.UInt16";
    case "int": return "System.Int32";
    case "uint": return "System.UInt32";
    case "long": return "System.Int64";
    case "ulong": return "System.UInt64";
    case "char": return "System.Char";
    case "float": return "System.Single";
    case "double": return "System.Double";
    case "bool": return "System.Boolean";
    case "decimal": return "System.Decimal";
    case "void": return "System.Void";
    case "object": return "System.Object";
    default: return userType;
}
```

Comment: I think he wants, given the text "string" or "int", to get to typeof(System.String) and typeof(System.Int32).  I.e. he doesn't necessarily have *a* string or int, he has the *name* "string" or "int".

Comment: But that will never work because you need to pass in the fully qualified name.

Comment: Your `case "int"` is missing a closing quote, and you could remove the redundant `return "void"` and take advantage of fall-through. Also, I don't know how performance would be affected (I would assume it would be impacted), but using something like `Double.GetType().ToString()` would probably be more elegant and bug-resistant. But that's personal preference, IMO.

Comment: I found that code, I just switched around each case (it was returning the clr type from the alias, the opposite of what the OP wants).

Answer (score 2):

`string`, `int`, and every other keyword is just that: a *keyword*. It's merely a shortcut to writing `String` or `Int32` or `Double` all the time. You would have to simply use their fully qualified names, but I don't know why you are opposed to simply using their full names, and not their keywords.

The only way I see of mapping keywords to fully qualified names would simply be a `switch` statement. There's no method that I'm aware of that will do what you're asking.

Comment: If you really need this functionality, seems like a `switch` statement wouldn't be so bad given that the mapping already exists.  This would be the cleanest approach (and maybe the only).  +1

Comment: I am not opposed to using their full names. But, I don't get to choose what gets passed in for nameOfTheType. I just need it to work.

Answer (score 2):

```
static readonly Dictionary<String, String> types = new Dictionary<String, String>()
{
    { "string", "System.String" },
    { "sbyte", "System.SByte" },
    { "byte", "System.Byte" },
    { "short", "System.Int16" },
    { "ushort", "System.UInt16" },
    { "int", "System.Int32" },
    { "uint", "System.UInt32" },
    { "long", "System.Int64" },
    { "ulong", "System.UInt64" },
    { "char", "System.Char" },
    { "float", "System.Single" },
    { "double", "System.Double" },
    { "bool", "System.Boolean" },
    { "decimal", "System.Decimal" },
    { "void", "System.Void" },
    { "object", "System.Object" }
};

private void Execute(String user_type)
{
    String type;
    if (!types.TryGetValue(user_type, out type))
    {
        type = user_type;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The Type name strings are originating from somewhere, and if that somewhere can be forced to create the Type name string in the following way using the .FullName property of the Type class, then you will not get the short form that you indicated is problematic:

```
string obj = ""; // using obj as an example - could be of any data type
string bestTypeName = obj.GetType().FullName; // produces "System.String"
```

Comment: You don't have to do any of that, passing in obj.GetType.ToString() would have the same effect.  The user wants to take the string literal "int" and get a Type object that corresponds to System.Int32.  I had the same confusion.

Comment: Except that the user asked if there is "a better way to do this all together" and that's how I chose to respond.

Comment: But it is not addressing the problem.  Of course "".GetType.FullName gives the correct name, but the OP does not have a type object to work from, they have a string.

Comment: Put it this way; if the OP already had the object, why would he need to use Type.GetType()?  He could simply call GetType() on the object itself, so this is pointless.

Comment: @Ed Swangren: I didn't indicate the OP had a Type object to work from and so there would be no use of me defending it. Instead I spoke about strings "originating from somewhere". I focused on a potential issue at the origin of the problem when invited to produce "a better way to do this all together".

Comment: *sigh*, ok, but your example does not reflect the problem *at all*, so your "solution" is not helpful.

Comment: My solution is only helpful under the circumstance I outlined in my post when responding to the author's invite. Put another way I wouldn't have had the flexibility if the author hadn't invited other solutions. I haven't stated anything different to your four comments than I outlined in my post, and haven't stepped outside the bounds of what the author requested. Sorry you feel exasperated. I too feel slightly exasperated from reiterating the same thing over and over again!